# Cannot Connect Keycloak docker to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, docker, keycloak, mssql-jdbc

I'm using a docker image of keycloak and trying to connect to SQL Server.

I have the database "keycloak" created in the database and here's my DockerFile

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.0 

ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin


ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start", "--hostname-strict=false", "--auto-build", "--proxy=edge", "--db=mssql", "--db-url-host=***", "--db-username=***", "--db-password=***"]
```

When I build and run this, the tables get automatically created in the 'keycloak' database. However, after waiting for keycloak to run, it crashes in the cmd and I get errors like

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK_CLI_SCOPE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CLIENT_SCOPE'

I fixed this error but I still get more endless errors and it never seemed to work. Last error I got was

> Cannot start server in developlment/production mode

Any idea why this is happening? Am I missing anything in the docker file? Any idea if keycloak actually works with SQL Server?

Thanks!

Comment: Either you use for now start-dev or you need to configure more stuff to run in production mode, check http://www.mastertheboss.com/keycloak/getting-started-with-keycloak-powered-by-quarkus/

Comment: Try removing volume with database where keycloak previously tried to apply migrations.